# AllJoyn Explorer does not show interfaces programmed in AllJoyn 14.12

Tags: alljoyn, windowsiot

I am playing with AllJoyn and Windows 10. I installed Windows 10 and tried the samples provided like MockAdapter and so on. These devices AllJoyn explorer displays, but if I install AllJoyn 14.12 on other linux computer and run basic_service, then nothing is displayed in AllJoyn Explorer. But basic service is using AllJoyn bus provided by Windows 10. Any help?
Thank you, guys!

Comment: is there a reason not to use the current version (15.09) on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The Alljoyn Explorer uses the AboutAnnounce feature and not the AdvertisedName feature of the Alljoyn Framework.

The basic_services uses the AdvertisedName feature and does not use the AboutAnnounce feature, hence it is not discovered by the Alljoyn Explorer.